# Mysql random is always showing same pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a table named questions and the fields are

```
ID -- QUESTION      --- OPTIONS-- CORRECT_OPTION
 1     some question     1,2,3  --    1
 2     some question     1,2,3  --    2
 3     some question     1,2,3  --    3
 4     some question     1,2,3  --    2
```

And here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND()
```

When i call this query the random function is working well but :-
When i take the question after some time the rand() function is repeating the same pattern which i got earlier!. why this happens? is there any alternative for rand() ? or how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the random works good , you may have `session` where you are outputing the results

Comment: I'm  using phonegap for developing my app and my backend is in php so i think it is not possible to create a session on php.

Comment: random works good in order by , try clear the history or cache

Answer (score 0):

Try that instead:

```
 SELECT *, RAND() AS rrank FROM questions ORDER BY rrank
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried here:

`select * from questions order by rand();`

it's working for me:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f6d/3

please check your db structure or your mysql version

Comment: Yes i checked your code but when i run sql i can see that some time the first row is not changing and others are changing.

Comment: that's because you have so few rows, add more rows and you will see a difference